# Customize input fields and buttons in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I'm using C# and I'm very new to Unity. I added buttons and input fields programatically. I'd like to change the background color of both, and I'd like to add a border around the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

The unity docs are very helpful

[GUI.Color](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-color.html)
[GUIStyle.border](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUIStyle-border.html)

Hope this gives you an idea of what you can do.